# iOs CSS keyboard appearing performance

Tags: html, ios, css, performance, keyboard

Just made my application mobile ready. I just noticed that sometimes the keyboard seems to be a bit 'slow' to appear when I hit an input field.

I have something like 20 inputs on one page. I created a test case with the same amount but didn't felt like it was responding more fast.

I am wondering if there is a performance trick for keyboard to appear quicker?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a web page? Show your code and tag the question for the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a **Webpage** which runs only on a server and is loaded through a browser like **Safari** or **Firefox** you can't effect the performance of the keyboard, because it is a system application which is not accessible through the browser.

**If it is necessary to change the keyboard features you need to create a native application.**